# Play framework without controllers?

Tags: playframework

I know about good points of MVC model, and I wrote several web application with Spring framework and PHP.

Sometimes we have very straightforward controllers that is just passing some parameters to the view. In this case, Spring framework can omit controllers, so that plain-old JSP can handle it with (humble) scriptlets.

Is there a same way to omit controllers in Play framework?

I read the [official document](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaRouting) and googled for a while, but I could not figure out that. Please help.

Comment: Parameters from GET request are added as parameter(s) to controller function. Controller choose view and pass the parameters. From my experience it is only one possibility. So you have to use at least one controller.